R Package 'systemfonts' Installation Fails in Docker with Missing ft2build.h
R Package 'systemfonts' Installation Fails in Docker with Missing ft2build.h
Problem
I'm trying to build a Docker image for an R application using r-base:4.3.2 as the base image. The build fails during renv::restore() when trying to install the systemfonts package with the error: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory.
Dockerfile
# Use r-base as the base image
FROM r-base:4.3.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libfreetype6 \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libharfbuzz-dev \
    libfribidi-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfontconfig1-dev \
    pandoc \
    curl \
    unzip \
    fonts-liberation \
    fontconfig \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install essential R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('renv'), repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org')"

# Set up renv
RUN mkdir -p renv/cache
ENV RENV_PATHS_CACHE=/usr/src/app/renv/cache

# Copy renv files
COPY renv.lock .
COPY .Rprofile .
COPY renv/activate.R renv/
COPY renv/settings.dcf renv/

# Restore the R environment
RUN R -e "renv::restore()"

COPY . .

# Download and install AWS CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && ./aws/install \
    && rm -rf awscliv2.zip aws

RUN aws --version

CMD ["Rscript", "create-dashboard-ecs.R"]

I keep getting this error:
1432.0 - Installing systemfonts ...                    FAILED
1432.3 Error: Error installing package 'systemfonts':
1432.3 =======================================
1432.3
1432.3 * installing *source* package 'systemfonts' ...
1432.3 ** package 'systemfonts' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
1432.3 ** using staged installation
1432.3 Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
1432.3 Using PKG_CFLAGS=
1432.3 Using PKG_LIBS=-lfontconfig -lfreetype
1432.3 ** libs
1432.3 using C++ compiler: 'g++ (Debian 13.2.0-13) 13.2.0'
1432.3 rm -f systemfonts.so caches.o cpp11.o dev_metrics.o font_matching.o font_registry.o ft_cache.o string_shape.o font_metrics.o font_fallback.o string_metrics.o emoji.o cache_store.o init.o unix/FontManagerLinux.o
1432.3 g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/src/app/renv/staging/1/cpp11/include'     -fPIC  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/reproducible-path/r-base-4.3.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Wformat -Werror=format-security -mbranch-protection=standard -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c caches.cpp -o caches.o
1432.3 In file included from caches.h:7,
1432.3                  from caches.cpp:1:
1432.3 ft_cache.h:9:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
1432.3     9 | #include <ft2build.h>
1432.3       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1432.3 compilation terminated.
1432.3 make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:200: caches.o] Error 1
1432.3 ERROR: compilation failed for package 'systemfonts'
1432.3 * removing '/usr/src/app/renv/staging/1/systemfonts'
1432.3 install of package 'systemfonts' failed [error code 1]
1432.3 Traceback (most recent calls last):
1432.3 13: renv::restore()
1432.3 12: renv_restore_run_actions(project, diff, current, lockfile, rebuild)
1432.3 11: renv_install_impl(records)
1432.3 10: renv_install_staged(records)
1432.3  9: renv_install_default(records)
1432.3  8: handler(package, renv_install_package(record))
1432.3  7: renv_install_package(record)
1432.3  6: withCallingHandlers(renv_install_package_impl(record), error = function(e) writef("FAILED"))
1432.3  5: renv_install_package_impl(record)
1432.3  4: r_cmd_install(package, path)
1432.3  3: r_exec_error(package, output, "install", status)
1432.3  2: abort(all)
1432.3  1: stop(fallback)
1432.3 Execution halted

I've tried installing libfreetype6 and libfreetype6-dev
What additional system dependencies do I need to install to resolve the missing ft2build.h error and successfully build the systemfonts R package?
It is part of the tidyverse dependency tree in my renv.lock

The DESCRIPTION file states that system requirements are fontconfig, freetype2. Perhaps you could also add freetype2 and see if it helps?

freetype2 isn't a package its already installed via libfreetype6

I was able to fix it by specifying the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
So adding this line ended up resolving it
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig

I got the same question except the error info showed me some tips
* installing *source* package ‘systemfonts’ ...
** package ‘systemfonts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package fontconfig was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fontconfig.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'fontconfig', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Package 'freetype2', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lfontconfig -lfreetype
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ (Anaconda gcc) 11.2.0’
rm -f systemfonts.so caches.o cpp11.o dev_metrics.o font_matching.o font_registry.o ft_cache.o string_shape.o font_metrics.o font_fallback.o string_metrics.o emoji.o cache_store.o init.o unix/FontManagerLinux.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/lib/R/library/cpp11/include' -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/include -I/home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/lib    -fpic  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1728291269090/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.4.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix   -c caches.cpp -o caches.o
In file included from caches.h:7,
                 from caches.cpp:1:
ft_cache.h:9:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <ft2build.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:204: caches.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘systemfonts’

As the info said
Package fontconfig was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fontconfig.pc'

I found the .pc file in my own dir using find /home/fangyy -name fontconfig.pc and added the path to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/fangyy/miniconda3/envs/r4.4.1/lib/pkgconfig/

Problem solved
DONE(systemfont)

